# Child element isn't being selected properly if used variable inside selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select tbody element of a table but it's not working properly. I have a table -

```
<table id="dislike_view_<?php some_func(); ?>">
<tr><td>USER</td><td>DATE</td></tr>
<tbody>
<tr><td>aj0ob</td><td>06/05/2018</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to add html before first child of tbody. But it's adding the html twice. It adds the HTML before first child of table and before first child of tbody. Here's my jquery code -

```
$('<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>').prependTo('#dislike_view_'+id+' > tbody');
```

`var id` is being called properly, i've tested it with other things. Here's a screenshot of what I am getting -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVhz8.jpg
I only want the html before the first element of tbody.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="someid">
<thead>
 <tr><td>USER</td><td>DATE</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr><td>aj0ob</td><td>06/05/2018</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to append a row before first row.

```
$('<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>').prependTo('tbody tr:first');
```

check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1s8m48t7/

Comment: `$('<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>').prependTo('#dislike_view_'+id+' > tbody tr:first');` This is the result of your code - https://imgur.com/a/ugnNwtW

Comment: Check your JSFIDDLE result. You posted it here without even checking your result.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to prepend it to the `<tr>` rather than the `<tbody>`. Have you tried getting rid of `tr:first`?

Comment: That is in my question. without the `tr:first`

Comment: You could use the `.insertBefore()` method with your current selector also.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode same result with .insertBefore()

Comment: As it should. I'm going off the fiddle provided in this answer. As for your code, my guess is that by not putting the first `<tr>` inside of the `<thead>`, it's implicitly putting it inside of a `<tbody>`, thus doing it twice. You could add the pseudo `tbody:last`, or, ya know, just format your table properly.

Comment: I believe there's something wrong in the selector. I tried adding `thead` but getting same result.

Comment: @user3551009 Thank you for trying but it didn't work for me. Could you please remove your answer so I can delete this post. (just noticed I put something here that I shouldn't disclose) Posts that has more than 1 answer cannot be deleted. Thank you